# activiti-app.war it not getting explored in Tomcat8

Tags: tomcat8

05-Dec-2016 20:55:23.842 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase /usr/share/tomcat8/webapps/activiti-app inseen specified, and will be ignored
05-Dec-2016 20:55:44.749 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enablogger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilatio
08:55:50,685 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  - Cannot search for matching files underneath URL /webapps/activiti-app.war*/WEB-INF/classes/com/activiti/conf/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [war:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/activiti-app.war*/WEB-INF/classes/com/activiti/conf/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path bin the file system: war:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/activiti-app.war*/WEB-INF/classes/com/activiti/conf/
        at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:212)
        at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:212)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:598)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.java:92
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:419)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:273)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:140)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:265)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:229)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:196)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at com.activiti.servlet.WebConfigurer.contextInitialized(WebConfigurer.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
08:55:50,719 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext  - Exception encountered during context initiresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure during classpath scanning; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry !/ot found in /var/cache/tomcat8/temp/jar_cache5590291403178717066.tmp
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:140)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:265)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:229)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:196)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at com.activiti.servlet.WebConfigurer.contextInitialized(WebConfigurer.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry !/com/activiti/repository/ not found in /var/cache/tomcat8/temp/jar_cache5590291403178717066.tmp
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:142)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:89)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingJarResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:509)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:416)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:273)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java
        ... 26 more
05-Dec-2016 20:55:50.720 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details wilate container log file

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy activiti-explorer.war to web apps directory of tomcat, and start apache tomcat server. Once started go to http://localhost:8080/activiti-explorer (port may vary according to your installation of tomcat)